# Extjs - Set icon to tab using setIconCls

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I would like to set an icon to the tab but not in it's properties. I would like to do it later using `setIconCls` but i keep getting: `Cannot call method 'setIcon' of undefined` . I did it with the buttons but idk how to do it with tabs.

```
{
            title: 'What's New?',
            itemId: 'updatesTab',
            //id: 'updates',

            items: [
```

--

```
Ext.getCmp('updatesTab').setIconCls('test');
```

Comment: The symptoms you describe, together with comments indicate that you're not retrieving either a tabpanel component (or any component) with your getCmp() call. Can you provide more of you're layout and further context as to when you're call this function?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `itemId` with `Ext.getCmp`, only `id`. So you should either set the id property of you tab, or reference through `parnetComponent.getComponent(itemId)`

Comment: setting the id property didn't work. can you please explain how to use parentComponemt ?

Comment: I can, but setting the id should work. Did you get the same error when setting the id? Or the icon just didn't change?

Comment: yes i got the same error Cannot call method 'setIcon' of undefined

Comment: hmmm, Was the tab initialized before the call? Was the id unique? Was it spelled correctly? If all is true, than I don't think I can debug it with the available information..